# If $|x| \le 2$, prove that $\frac{|x^2-4x+3|}{|x^2-2x+2|} \le 15$.

Tags: inequality

If $|x| \le 2$, prove that $\frac{|x^2-4x+3|}{|x^2-2x+2|} \le 15$.

I am stuck at the step $|x-3|/|x-1|$ and not able to continue it

Comment: How did you get to this step?  Where did the inequality go?

Comment: You must have made a mistake somewhere, because $x^2-2x+2$ is not $(x-1)^2$ (at least that's what it looks to me like you've done).

Comment: In the denominator part, since $x^2 - 2x + 2$ is more than $x^2 -2x + 1$ then I used the latter part and factorize it besides the numerator thus both parts have the same factor which can be cancelled, i.e. $x-1$

Comment: @warwar05 There is an infinite discontinuity of $\frac{x^2-4x+3}{x^2-2x+2} = \frac{x-3}{x-1}$ around $x=1$. Try from the step $x^2-4x+3-15(x^2-2x+2)≤0$ and compare with $-14x^2+28x-14$.

Comment: @TobyMak It's technically not a discontinuity, just a point where the function is undefined, with a vertical asumptote. Also, as I said in my previous comment, $x^2-2x+2$ is not $(x-1)^2$, so your first equality is false.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $$|x|\le 2 \implies \frac{|x^2-4x+3|}{|x^2-2x+2|} \le \frac{|x^2|+|4x|+3}{(x-1)^2+1} \le \frac{4+8+3}{1} =15$$

Thus if $|x|\le 2$, then $\frac{|x^2-4x+3|}{|x^2-2x+2|}\le 15$

Comment: That is such a clever solution.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I am glad that you liked it.

Comment: That's very clever indeed (+1)

Comment: I would say that this is probably the intended solution, seeing as how the actual bound is closer to $1.5$, so $15$ is ridiculously high.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$ y =|\frac{x^2-4x+3}{x^2-2x+2}|$$
$ y =\frac{x^2-4x+3}{x^2-2x+2}$ or $y = -\frac{x^2-4x+3}{x^2-2x+2}$

First let us take the former case in which the expression is positive

$$ y =\frac{x^2-4x+3}{x^2-2x+2} $$
$$ y(x^2-2x+2) =x^2-4x+3$$
$$(y-1)x^2-(2y-4)x +(2y-3)=0$$

Now we know that $|x|\le2$. This means that $x \in [-2,2]$. This shows that x is a real number and will have real values.

In the expression above, x will only assume real values if the determinant is greater than or equal to zero.

$$(2y-4)^2-4(2y-3)(y-1) \ge 0$$
I hope you can take it from here. Just solve the inequality above and check the second case. Let me know if you don't find the answer

Answer (score 2):

As a traditional alternative to the clever and short solution by [Mohammad Riazi-Kermani](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2698754/505767), note that $x^2-2x+2>0$ then

$$\frac{|x^2-4x+3|}{|x^2-2x+2|} \le 15\implies\frac{|(x-3)(x-1)|}{x^2-2x+2} \le 15$$

then consider two cases with also $|x|\le 2$

- $x<1 \quad \lor \quad x>3 \implies -2\le x<1  \implies \frac{(x-3)(x-1)}{x^2-2x+2} \le 15$
- $1\le x\le3\implies 1\le x\le2 \implies \frac{(x-3)(x-1)}{x^2-2x+2} \ge 15$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks to have pointed out the mistake! Now it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

$$\left| \dfrac{x^2-4x+3}{x^2-2x+2} \right| =\left|1- \frac{2x-1}{x^2-2x+2}\right| \leqslant 1+\left|\frac{2x-1}{(x-1)^2+1} \right| \leqslant 1+\left|\frac51 \right|  <15$$
for $x \in [-2, 2]$